# Suppose there is an update query in a procedure. How to check whether the data is updated or not?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Suppose there is an update query in a procedure. How to check whether the data is updated or not?

Comment: without using triggers.

Comment: If the transaction commits, the data is updated.  Oracle is ACID-compliant:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID.  You can see the results using a `select`.

Comment: E.g an UPDATE in conditional code (if), or always executed?

Comment: Do you just want to know how many rows were affected by the update - so you know if the conditions were met for any rows, for example? it isn't really clear what your goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call DML inside PL/SQL procedure and want to check if any data were updated then you can use implicit cursor attribute %rowcount. You need to call it immediately after you DML.

```
update table
set some_column = 'Some value'
where id = p_id;

if sql%rowcount = 0 then
  dbms_output.put_line('No rows have been updated')
elsif sql%rowcount = 1 then
  dbms_output.put_line('1 row has been updated')
else
  dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount||' rows have been updated')
end if;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Gordon commented all the Oracle commands are ACID compliant so if the transaction is complete and commited then you can fire a select query to check if the update is done.

You can also use the `ORA_ROWSCN` to see the changes. Something like this:

```
SQL> select ora_rowscn from myTable
  2  where column2 = 102
  3  /

ORA_ROWSCN
----------
  33526761

SQL> update myTable
  2      set column1 = 1
  3      where column2 = 102
  4  /

1 row updated.

SQL> commit
  2  /

Commit complete.

SQL> select ora_rowscn from myTable
  2  where column2 = 102
  3  /

ORA_ROWSCN
----------
  33435234

SQL>
```